# What's the best way to for an object to identify itself and run specific logic?

Tags: c#, xna-4.0

I have a class designed to display a text pop up in game and I'm going to use this for two different situations:

- to display a RED "-1" and,
- a yellow "+25"

For the "-1" I want the text to appear and then I want it to fade off screen therefore I'm reducing the color values and alpha to zero and shifting it's position slightly and then later deleting the object/text popup.

For the "+25" I want to move this text popup over to an icon of gold coins and then delete.

My question is, since I'm using this class for two different events, both of which would have different logic to execute, how best would I go about differentiating between what text pop up I'm displaying and therefore what .

I thought of maybe having a switch/if statement using a string.

E.g

string for -1 would be "enemyLived"

string for "+25" would be "goldPickup"

and I would check

`if (this.identity == "enemyLived")
      do logic
else (this.identity =="goldPickup")
    do logic`

But I was curious if a more experienced coder had a suggestion for a "better" designed check.

Comment: If you are going for the `switch` or `if`, consider using an `enum` rather than specific string values. I would personally go for LB2's approach though.

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like a classic case for OOD and use of inheritance to solve this problem.

Create an interface that describes method for general action, e.g. `PopupTransition()`, then have two classes, one for negative points, the other positive.  Have each one provide their own implementation on how transition occurs (fading or moving or whatever).  When event occurs, instantiate the respective type, and pass it to your general handler, who doesn't care what event it is, and will just call `PopupTransition` at the right moment.  You can easily extend it if you suddenly want to support other transitions..

Comment: +1, though depending on how much logic is the same (if it's almost none), I might prefer an interface.

Comment: @Magus.  Good point.  My general approach in such cases is still to just about always use an interface.  If there is a lot of shared code, with the interface I also create an abstract class that implements the interface containing all the common code.  Then you simply inherit from the class and provide the missing pieces.  Then if you have another implementation that doesn't share it, it simply implements interfaces and does its own nine-yards.

Comment: Great suggestion thank you! Whilst this is not a challenging piece of code I just wanted to pick the brains of those with more experience, or even just simply a fresh viewpoint (been working on this game for a while now :P ) 
P.S What does the abbreviation OOD stand for? Do you mean OOP (object oriented programming?)

Comment: @LB2: True, though I'd prefer to do that through a member rather than an abstract class, so any number of different 'nine yards' can be included in any implementation as needed.

Comment: @craigwp2703, OOD = Object Oriented Design